# Android camera, take picture(s) and save as multipage PDF, then upload to server via <input type="file" />

Tags: pdf, file-upload, yii2, android-camera

I have a webform with  and want to open it on smartphone - than take pictures of some documents which need to be merged in one PDF, and on the end this file need to be uploaded to server.

My solution is to use Google Drive to upload PDF (scan) to GDrive and then somehow download this file from gdrive to server via some sort of widget (any links appreciate) installed on website.

Maybe someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but my answer might help others. I also face the same challenge and implemented a custom solution based on Javascript and Since you are using web form so this solution will perfectly fits on your need.

You have to use **[JSPdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)** javascript library, JSPdf provide you pdf object in your browser and you can upload it download it and there are many other thing to play with.

First you have to initialize JSPdf object as per your requirement. I am creating PDF with page size width:500px and height 500px.

```
pdf = new jsPDF("l", "pt", [500,500]);
```

Simply when you will take picture from camera you will have each picture in form of base64, that base64 format you have to insert in JSPdf object

```
 pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
```

you can repeat the above code to add pictures from camera as much as you want, at the back-end these images are compiling and creating pdf document where each page have each images in sequence.

Once you are done, you can get PDF object in form of **base64** object using below code that you can upload to any server.

```
pdf.output('datauristring')
```

above is only pdf part, you can find complete working example including camera part here [Javascript Component to Scan Document](https://www.bloggy.club/2020/05/javascript-component-to-scan-document.html)